# Is the following divide and conquer recursive algorithm for the exponentiation more efficient than the iterative one for large numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity, big-o, exponentiation

I have the two following algorithms. My analysis says that both of them are O(m^2+4^n) i.e they are equivalent for big numbers. Is this right?. Note that `m` and `n` are the bits numbers for `x` and `y`

```
def pow1(x, y):

    if y == 0:
        return 1
    temp = x
    while y > 1:
        y -= 1
        temp *= x
    return temp
```

```
def pow2(x, y):

    if y == 0:
        return 1
    temp = pow2(x, y//2)
    if y & 1:    return temp * temp * x
    return temp * temp
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether the divide-and-conquer algorithm is more efficient depends on a ton of factors. In Python it is more efficient.

Your analysis is right; assuming standard grade-school multiplication, divide-and-conquer does fewer, more expensive multiplications, and asymptotically that makes total runtime a wash (constant factors probably matter -- I'd still guess divide-and-conquer would be faster because the majority of the work is happening in optimized C rather than in Python loop overhead, but that's just a hunch, and it'd be hard to test given that Python doesn't use an elementary multiplication algorithm).

Before going further, note that big integer multiplication in Python is little-o of m^2. In particular, it uses karatsuba, which is around O(m^0.58 n) for an m-bit integer and an n-bit integer with m<=n.

The small terms using ordinary multiplication won't matter asymptotically, so focusing on the large ones we can replace the multiplication cost and find that your iterative algorithm is around O(4^n m^1.58) and your divide-and-conquer solution is around O(3^n m^1.58).

Comment: If we're talking about really large numbers, `pow2` is somewhat constrained by the stack limit in how large a value of `y` it can handle. The high constant cost of calling a user-defined function may be more significant as well. `pow1` can be adapted to use repeated squaring rather than a linear chain of products.

Comment: Playing devil's advocate: For most values of `x` we'll run out of time in the universe before we blow the stack in `pow2`. As to the high constant cost of function calls I agree that probably matters (especially for smallish inputs), but it doesn't for asymptotic estimates, and they'd probably want to use the built-in `pow` function for any real-world use. Also, isn't `pow1` adapted to use repeated squaring basically just the iterative counterpart to `pow2`?

Comment: Yes :) That's why I suggested it.

Comment: Makes sense :) I toyed with pointing out that either of their solutions could be iterative or recursive and eventually decided it would detract from their actual question. Do you think it would be a good idea to edit my answer and add that sort of information?